# How to access current table rows specific cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to retrieve the value of the 'surname' column, only of the current table row upon click.

What is the best way to print this?

`$(this).parent();` [See my: jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mstry00z/2/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mstry00z/3/)

```
  function fooFunction(thisObj) {
    alert(thisObj.parentNode.previousSibling.previousSibling.innerHTML);
  }
```

in jquery

```
  function fooFunction(thisObj) {
    alert($(thisObj).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(2)").html());
  }
```

Comment: Thank you **very** much!

Comment: @Ben : this won't work if you change the position of your surname column

Comment: @ChanchalYadav Thanks for the heads up! My table won't be changing so for the current scenario this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class for your surname column i.e. class="surname".
Now By clicking on click

```
$('clickbtn').click(function(){ alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.surname').html())});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Using jQuery, you can do the following

```
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).parent().prev().text());
  });
});
```

What's happening here is that on document ready event, I am binding a click event to all the `a` tags in the document (you should be more specific using id/class on `a` tag.

In the event, I am asking anchor tag to not to do it's default thing i.e go to # in this case.

Then, I am using jQuery to go to my parent and then the item just before it and alerting its text.

Hope this is helpful. See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mstry00z/6/)

Comment: **Very** helpful! Thank you!